# How to check is my reverse proxy server is working or not

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

Recently I had set up my reverse proxy server for my node js application rest api service with nginx server but how I know that proxy server is really working.

I'm doing like this

My node app rest api :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 

var router = express.Router();  

router.get('/',function(req,res){
    // console.log("Route = /");
    res.json({"success" : 1})
});

app.use('/api/v2', router);

app.listen(8080);
```

which is running on server 1 with pvt ip address is APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS

My reverse proxy server config :

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Like pointing your web browser or curl to the ` APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS`?

Comment: yes I am calling my rest api from my android app with url http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:8080/ and it is responding with the correct response but how will I know that proxy server comes between my app and app server while calling for data.

Comment: Why not testing by doing a test call to `http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:80`?

Comment: Because I'm running my node js rest api service on port 8080

Comment: Mehdi is right - to test it you will need to make a request to `http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:80`. That's how reverse proxies work - your upstream server is the one listening on port 8080 and your reverse proxy is listening on port 80 (according to your nginx config)

Comment: @gregnr How to call this URL of my rest API 

http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:8080/api/v3/categories/ 

running on my app server with IP address APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS and the proxy server is running on PROXY_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS

Is my configuration is right or wrong

Comment: Make a request to `http://PROXY_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:80/api/v3/categories`

Comment: @gregnr thanks it's working